# Custom Widget Not working properly in wordpress 4.8

Tags: wordpress

I have created the custom widget area it is not working properly, I have done everything fine i think:

```
function ci_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => 'Top Leader for CI',
        'id'            => 'custom-header-widget1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ));
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'ci_widgets_init' );
```

And I am displaying my widget by using the below code unable to widget output, I am able to widgets in admin area but in front end not displaying.

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="header-widget-area" class="chw-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget1' ); ?>
    </div>
```